# Apache2 ignoring some rewrites

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm having the weirdest problem with a previous developer's URL rewrites after moving this custom CMS to a new server. Observe this snippet of the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the URL doesn't end in a slash, redirect them to the equivalent that does (for canonical/SEO purporses)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(health|nutrition|fitness|directory|coupons|download|kids|faq|signup|menu|snp|myaccount|myschool|printmenu)(.*)$ /$1$2/ [R=301,L,QSA,NS]

# Health Pages
RewriteRule ^health/$ health.php [L]
RewriteRule ^health/([^/]+)/$ health.php?title=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^health/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ health_article_details.php?cat=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

The first part of the Health rewrite:

```
# Health Pages
RewriteRule ^health/$ health.php [L]
```

works as expected, but:

```
RewriteRule ^health/([^/]+)/$ health.php?title=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^health/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ health_article_details.php?cat=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

don't forward the rest of the URL segment as an argument. I threw a `print_r($_REQUEST);` in at the start of health.php and with a URL of `http://www.foo.com/health/a/b/`, I get this output:

```
Array ()
```

Why is this happening instead of:

```
Array ( [title] => a )
```

Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You put the `print_r($_REQUEST);` in the wrong file.  The rewrite that matches that URL gets sent to `health_article_details.php`.

For that URL you should get:

```
Array ( [cat] => a, [title] => b )
```

Why you got anything at all I don't know.  Possibly health_article_details.php `include()`s health.php.

Comment: I suspect you're misinterpreting the rewrites, as the system works fine on the origin server, and health_article_details.php isn't being touched at all.

Comment: Maybe I am... but these rules are not complex so I think it unlikely. Maybe there are more rewrites or other config that's not in your question that affects the URL or maybe you pasted the wrong URL.  I don't understand how `/health/a/b/` could possible match `^health/$` or `^health/([^/]+)/$` without something mangling it first.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, the rewrites ought never have worked. On advice given by someone in freenode's #httpd channel, I changed the rewrites like so:

```
# Health Pages
RewriteRule ^health/$ health.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^health/([^/]+)/$ health.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^health/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ health_article_details.php?cat=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Without `QSA` no query strings were being forwarded. I have no idea why this worked in its original context, but as of this moment it no longer matters.